# How can I change PHP date format

Tags: php

A user selects dating like 22-Sep-2010 from jQuery datepicker.

Is there a php function to convert that date to 22/09/2010?
Could strtottime or mktime be used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$newTime = date('d/M/Y',strtotime($oldTime));
```

where $oldTime is the value from the date picker.

Answer (score 0):

**To convert the date format from dd-mmm-yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy** in php,

```
<?php

$dt='22-Sep-2010';
$dt=date('d/m/Y',strtotime($dt));
echo $dt;

?>
```

The o/p will be, `22/09/2010`